# Delete all text before and after a certain string

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have some URL like the following

```
http://www.SOMEURL.com/first-category/1343381-example-text-text-text-text-2000-a.html
```

What I want is to simple delete all of the text before and after the number `1343381` which is an ID.

I read that I could do this using Notepad++ Regular Expressions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If we can assume that `SOMEURL` and `first-category` don't contain digits, we can simply search for the first non-empty string of numbers and delete everything else.

**Pattern:**

```
Find what:    (.*?)(\d+).*
Replace with: \2
```

**How it works:**

- `.*` is any arbitrary string of characters
- `?` makes `.*` *lazy*, i.e., it matches as few characters as possible
- `\d+` is a non-empty string of digits
- `()` groups characters, where `\2` refers to the second group

For more information about Regular Expressions, click [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

**Example:**

```
http://www.SOMEURL.com/first-category/1343381-example-text-text-text-2000-a.html
http://www.SOMEOTHERURL.com/some-category/1343382-example-more-text-2001-b.html
```

gets replaced with

```
1343381
1343382
```